# Why is response.getStatus() returning 200 OK even when the actual response is not

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

I am implementing a feature that logs all the access to my API in a log file. In it, I have response status code as well as some information related to each access. I retrieve the status code by `response.getStaus()` as shown in AppLogFilter.

However, it always logs 200 OK even when the actual response status is 400 or 405.
[image]

What could I be the problem here?

**Filter Config**

```
package com.example.kasahararestapi.filter;

import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class FilterConfig {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<ApiLogFilter> filterRegistrationBean() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<ApiLogFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registrationBean.setFilter(new ApiLogFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/api/items/*");
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

**ApiLogFilter**

```
@Component
public class ApiLogFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiLogFilter.class);


    @Override
    public final void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long processingTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;


        logger.info(
                "{} {} {} {}", request.getMethod(),
                request.getRequestURI(), response.getStatus(), processingTime);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: you have called that method before `filterChain.doFilter(request, response);` so the default value is `200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
logger.info(
                "{} {} {} {}", request.getMethod(),
                request.getRequestURI(), response.getStatus(), processingTime);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
```

To

```
filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
logger.info(
                "{} {} {} {}", request.getMethod(),
                request.getRequestURI(), response.getStatus(), processingTime);
```

*Reason:*
The name chain suggests that you have a sequence of filters, with each filter doing some processing and then passing on to the next in sequence, so each object has a chain member to point to the next filter in the sequence, which `gets called after the filter has performed its own processing.` The last in the sequence will then probably have `null` as the chain value, or it knows on its own that it is the last one in the sequence. In other words, you are logging the info *before* the filter has performed it processing which results in status as `200`